# DynamoDB update item in case of item's value

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Im trying to write a query which update the item only if value "taken" attribute doesn't equal "yes". Is it possibile to do that using dynamoDB? Right now dynamoDB doesn't check the condition. It updates my item and doesn't check if "taken" doesn't equal "yes"

```
  var params = {
      TableName:"usersRinger1",
      Key:{
          "userID": self.event.session.user.userId,
          "medicine": User.USERNAME.current.lastDrug
        },
        ConditionExpression: ':p <> :u',
        UpdateExpression: "set info.taken = :r, info.whatTime=:a",
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ":r": "yes",
            ":a": actualTime,
            ':p' : 'info.taken',
            ':u' : "yes"
        },
        ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
    };
    docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue on `ConditionExpression`. The `:p` is an attribute name. It should go into `ExpressionAttributeNames`.

```
ExpressionAttributeNames : {
    ":p" : "info.taken"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Attributes names **MUST** always start with **#** character and not **:**
(**:** is used for attribute values **NOT** attribute names.) You are actually comparing 2 strings in your condition "info.taken" and "yes" which always returns False! and not the 'info.taken' attribute's values to "yes".

you should change your condition expression to the following:

```
ConditionExpression: '#p <> :u',
```

and your attribute values to:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues:{
    ':r': 'yes',
    ':a': actualTime,
    ':u' : 'yes'
    }
```

and add:

```
ExpressionAttributeNames:{
    '#p' : 'info.taken'}
```

From AWS DynamoDB Doc:

> Use the # character in an expression to dereference an attribute name.
>
> Tokens that begin with the : character are expression attribute values, which are placeholders for the actual value at runtime.